# office addin not loading in Mac - Office.initialize event is it supported in Mac ? office.js

Tags: office-js

My office add-in is not loading in Mac Excel App, i looked into the documentation at  http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/office.initialize, it is not indicating if **Office.initialize** method is supported or not in Mac in Excel App.

Does someone know if its supported? i dont have the MAC machine so i couldn't test it. this is the report given by Microsoft in their add-in validation report.

Comment: Yes, it is supported, but you might need to be on the early release stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office.initialize is a fundamental part of add-ins; if a host supports add-ins then it supports Office.initialize. Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and Outlook for Mac all support add-ins.